# Deblurring algorithm in the Fourier domain

Tags: c++, opencv, fft

I'm trying to implement a deconvolution algorithm in Fourier transformed domain. I've a working implementation by myself in Matlab, and I want to translate it to C++ using OpenCV library.

Basically what I do is to extract the gradients from an input image, I do some stuff in transformed domain and then I come back to space domain.

The problematic part to me is to perform this (element wise) division:

```
DFT(im) = ( conj( DFT(f) ) * DFT(image) + L2 * conj( DFT( gradKernel-x ) ) * DFT(mux) )+ ... ) / ( norm( DFT(f) )^2 + L2 * norm(gradKernel-x)^2 + ... )
```

`f` is a gaussian kernel that is defined in the code.
`DFT( gradKernel-x )` is the FFT of the gradient kernel in x direction, i.e. `DFT([1,-1])` zero-padded to the size of the blurred image. mux is an auxiliary variable to perform the deconvolution.

I decided to perform the division by magnitude and phase separately in transformed domain before performing an inverse DFT.

I don't know where is the error in my code, maybe in the division, maybe in the forward/inverse transform of my variables, in the gaussian kernel...

If somebody can help me, I'd very grateful.

Here is the critical part of the code (note that I simplified it before posting, so don't expect a good deblurring result if you try it, basically what I expect from this is a visually pleasant output image):

```
imH00=imread("Cameraman256.png",0);
if(!imH00.data)                             
{
    std::cout<<  "Could not open or find the image" << std::endl ;
    return -1;
}

imH00.convertTo(imH00,CV_32F,1.0/255.0,0.0);

// Gaussian Kernel
Mat ker1D=getGaussianKernel(ksize,sigma,CV_32F);
fkernel.create(imH00.size(),CV_32F);
// zero-padding
fkernel.setTo(Scalar::all(0));
temp=ker1D*ker1D.t();
temp.copyTo(fkernel(Rect(0,0,temp.rows,temp.cols)));

// Fourier transform
Mat planes[] = {Mat_<float>(fkernel), Mat::zeros(fkernel.size(), CV_32F)};
Mat ffkernel;
merge(planes, 2, ffkernel);
dft(ffkernel, ffkernel,DFT_COMPLEX_OUTPUT);

// Gradient filter in frequency domain, trying to do something similar to psf2otf([1;-1],size(imH00)); in Matlab.
dx=Mat::zeros(imH00.size(),CV_32F);
dx.at<float>(0,0)=1;
dx.at<float>(0,1)=-1;
Mat dxplanes[] = {Mat_<float>(dx), Mat::zeros(dx.size(), CV_32F)};
Mat fdx;
merge(dxplanes, 2, fdx);
dft(fdx, fdx,DFT_COMPLEX_OUTPUT);

dy=Mat::zeros(imH00.size(),CV_32F);
dy.at<float>(0,0)=1;
dy.at<float>(1,0)=-1;
Mat dyplanes[] = {Mat_<float>(dy), Mat::zeros(dy.size(), CV_32F)};
Mat fdy;
merge(dyplanes, 2, fdy);
dft(fdy, fdy,DFT_COMPLEX_OUTPUT);

// Denominators

Mat den1;
Mat den2;
Mat den21;
Mat den22;

// ||fdx||^2 and ||fdy||^2
mulSpectrums(fdx,fdx,den21,DFT_COMPLEX_OUTPUT,true); 
mulSpectrums(fdy,fdy,den22,DFT_COMPLEX_OUTPUT,true); 
add(den21,den22,den2);

mulSpectrums(ffkernel,ffkernel,den1,0,true);

imHk=imH00.clone();

mux=Mat::zeros(imH00.size(),CV_32F);
muy=Mat::zeros(imH00.size(),CV_32F);

// FFT imH00 
    Mat fHktplanes[] = {Mat_<float>(imH00), Mat::zeros(imH00.size(), CV_32F)};
    Mat fHkt;
    merge(fHktplanes, 2, fHkt);
    dft(fHkt, fHkt,DFT_COMPLEX_OUTPUT);

std::cout<<"starting deconvolution"<<std::endl;
for (int j=0; j<4; j++)
{
    // Deconvolution 

    // Gradients 

    Mat ddx(1,2,CV_32F,Scalar(0));
    ddx.at<float>(0,0)=1;
    ddx.at<float>(0,1)=-1;
    filter2D(imHk,dHx,CV_32F,ddx);

    Mat ddy(2,1,CV_32F,Scalar(0));
    ddy.at<float>(0,0)=1;
    ddy.at<float>(1,0)=-1;
    filter2D(imHk,dHy,CV_32F,ddy);


    mux=Scalar((float)-0.5*L1/L2);
    add(mux,dHx,mux);

    muy=Scalar((float)-0.5*L1/L2);
    add(muy,dHy,muy);

    // FFT mux, muy
    Mat fmuxplanes[] = {Mat_<float>(mux), Mat::zeros(mux.size(), CV_32F)};
    Mat fmux;
    merge(fmuxplanes, 2, fmux);
    dft(fmux, fmux,DFT_COMPLEX_OUTPUT);

    Mat fmuyplanes[] = {Mat_<float>(muy), Mat::zeros(muy.size(), CV_32F)};
    Mat fmuy;
    merge(fmuyplanes, 2, fmuy);
    dft(fmuy, fmuy,DFT_COMPLEX_OUTPUT);

    Mat num1,num2,num3,num,den;

    // Spectrums multiplication, complex conjugate
    mulSpectrums(fHkt,ffkernel,num1,DFT_COMPLEX_OUTPUT,true);
    mulSpectrums(fmux,fdx,num2,DFT_COMPLEX_OUTPUT,true);
    mulSpectrums(fmuy,fdy,num3,DFT_COMPLEX_OUTPUT,true);

    add(num2,num3,num2);
    add(num1,L2*num2,num);
    add(den1,L2*den2,den);

    // Division in polar coordinates

    Mat auxnum[2];
    split(num,auxnum);
    Mat auxden[2];
    split(den,auxden);

    Mat numMag,numPhase;
    magnitude(auxnum[0],auxnum[1],numMag);
    phase(auxnum[0],auxnum[1],numPhase);

    Mat denMag,denPhase;
    magnitude(auxden[0],auxden[1],denMag);
    phase(auxden[0],auxden[1],denPhase);

    Mat division[2];
    divide(numMag,denMag,division[0]);
    division[1]=numPhase-denPhase;

    polarToCart(division[0],division[1],division[0],division[1]);
    Mat fHk;
    merge(division,2,fHk);

    Mat imHkaux;
    Mat planesfHk[2];
    dft(fHk, imHkaux, DFT_INVERSE+DFT_SCALE);
    split(imHkaux,planesfHk);
    imHk=planesfHk[0]; // imHk is the Real part
}
imHk.convertTo(imHk,CV_8U,255);
imshow( "Deblurred image", imHk);
```

Thank you

Comment: Sorry, but I don't see a question in your post.

Comment: Well, the question is: what am I doing wrong?

Comment: Could you describe in more detail how it goes wrong? For example, do you get any error messages?

Comment: it provides visual unpleasant images like [this](http://imageshack.us/photo/my-images/819/imagebj.png/). After testing, I'm almost sure that problem is in the gradient filter and/or gaussian filter in Fourier domain.

Comment: If you are not completely sure where it goes wrong, I recommend you to run both the matlab code and the c++ code blockwise and see when the first differences occur. That should give you an indication of what to fix. You may need to expand your matlab code to do this, but maybe its not even neccesary.

Comment: I updated the question with my solution. Thank you

Comment: Please post and accept the solution rather than placing it in your question. Otherwise this question will retain the status of unanswered.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was in the Fourier transform of the filters. We need to shift filters kernels before transforming. This is the same that psf2otf function does in Matlab. If someone is interested, this simple code should perform the DFT of a Gaussian kernel which is not influenced by centering (as psf2otf):

```
float sigma=1.0;
short int ksize=13; // always odd

Mat ker1D=getGaussianKernel(ksize,sigma,CV_32F); //1D gaussian kernel
fkernel.create(myImage.size(),CV_32F); //

// zero-padding
fkernel.setTo(Scalar::all(0));
temp=ker1D*ker1D.t(); // 2D gaussian kernel, (Gaussian filter is separable)

int r=(ksize-1)/2; //radius

// shifting

temp(Rect(r,r,r+1,r+1)).copyTo(fkernel(Rect(0,0,r+1,r+1))); // q1
temp(Rect(r,0,r+1,r)).copyTo(fkernel(Rect(0,fkernel.cols-r,r+1,r))); // q2
temp(Rect(0,r,r,r+1)).copyTo(fkernel(Rect(fkernel.rows-r,0,r,r+1))); // q3
temp(Rect(0,0,r,r)).copyTo(fkernel(Rect(fkernel.rows-r,fkernel.cols-r,r,r))); // q4
// DFT
Mat planes[] = {Mat_<float>(fkernel), Mat::zeros(fkernel.size(), CV_32F)};
Mat ffkernel;
merge(planes, 2, ffkernel);
dft(ffkernel, ffkernel,DFT_COMPLEX_OUTPUT);
```